# Typescript: why array from HTMLCollection has Element[] type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have an HTMLCollection:

```
const appElem = document.querySelector("#app");
const appChildren = appElem?.children; // HTML collection
```

now if I convert this collection to an array it will be `Element[]`:

```
const appChildrenArr = appChildren && Array.from(appChildren); // Element[]
```

But why `appChildrenArr` has `Element[]` type, not `HTMLElement[]` type?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-violet-k6ec8q?file=/src/index.ts:130-209)

Comment: `HTMLCollection` != `HTMLElement[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they don't have to be HTMLElements. You could have an SVGElement there, as well, for example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element